# Constructor chaining giving method not defined

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock, constructor

I have the following class with constructor chaining , but the validations are returning `Method not found or incorrect signature`

class

```
@IsTest
global class CalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    private Map<String,HttpResponse> httpResponseMap = new Map<String,HttpResponse>();

   global CalloutMock(Map<String,HttpResponse> responseMap){
        if (responseMap != null) {
            httpResponseMap = responseMap;
        }
    }

   global CalloutMock(){
        CalloutMock(null);
    }

    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        System.debug('req end point hitting is ' + req.getEndpoint());
        return  httpResponseMap.get(req.getEndpoint());
  
    }

}
```

why is that ? and how do i resolve it?

Comment: You should use `this(null);` instead of `CalloutMock(null);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a different constructor, you should call `this(null);`, instead `CalloutMock(null);`. The latter would just call an instance method called `CalloutMock`, which is not exactly what you're doing.